# Cannot read property 'firstElementChild' of null, pdf.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf.js

I am trying to embedded pdf on my html page using `pdf.js`, with the help of [pdf viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf.js-viewer) blog,I have included `pdf.js` and `pdf.worker.js` in my html file, but when I open the page, nothing is embedded and I am getting below error

> `Cannot read property firstElementChild of null`

Please help me in this.

Thanks!

HTML Code:

```
<body>   

<div class="pdfjs">

</div> 
<script src="{% static 'pdf.js-viewer/pdf.js'%}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'pdf.js-viewer/pdf.worker.js'%}"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
      PDFJS.webViewerLoad('http://url/mypdf.pdf');
</script>
</body>
```

Checkout below error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'firstElementChild' of null
>       at Object.PDFViewer (http://url/pdf.js:17939:52)
>       at http://url/pdf.js:12985:21
>       at Object._initializeViewerComponents (http://url/pdf.js:12973:10)
>       at http://url/pdf.js:12884:16PDFViewer

Comment: Can you verify that the PDF loads in the first place?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, sorry but here I didn't get the **first place** means? Where I need to verify?

Comment: Verify that the PDF is accessible, and can be loaded from an external URL.

Comment: you may want to open issue for pdf.js-viewer at https://github.com/legalthings/pdf.js-viewer

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes that file is accessible, I have checked.

Comment: Crosspost at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/8703